# Hiding all files on desktop?

Tags: 10.10

I always had my `Desktop` folder empty, and so I deleted it. After restart, nautilus decided that it should use my home folder as a base, and now my desktop is cluttered with files from my home folder.

I tried recreating `Desktop` folder, nothing changed.

I tired setting `apps/nautilus/preferences/desktop_is_home_dir` key to true or false in gconf-editor, but nothing changed.

Also, I tried setting `apps/nautilus/preferences/show_desktop` key to false, it did hide all the icons, but also screws some visual effects.

Is there some way to convince nautilus back to using `~/Desktop` folder as a base folder for desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this to hide stuff on the Desktop
in the Terminal type

```
cd ~/Desktop
ls > .hidden
```

then press

```
CTRL+R
```

to refresh the desktop and no files.

or the other option is to install

[image: Install gnome-tweak-tool]Advanced Settings

[image]

Select Desktop from the sidebar

[image]

Turn OFF let file manager handle the desktop

Comment: I did that in my `~/`, and it seems to work. And I even got to get rid of that `Desktop` folder! Thanks!

Comment: @Rogach OK you're welcome
I expanded the answer with a nether option.